# Getting Partial Start message after starting the application

Tags: websphere, websphere-7, websphere-8

I've installed a default application and when I started the application I am getting the **partial start** message. 
What **log file** should I refer to check the the cause?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please look for the `SystemOut` and `SystemErr.log` files in the installed profile. e.g. 
`WAS_HOME/profiles/pofile-name/logs/server-name/`